# What is a def __call__(self,in_data) function used for in python and where is the in_data getting its value

Tags: python-2.7, neural-network, perceptron

I am actually a student and my teacher gave me this code to understand and use this code so i can continue to learn machine learning etc. I get that it is an AND function and i get what it is printing , the thing i cant understan is the def **call**(self,in_data): function and where does the "in_data" gets its value from? Because in my point of view all i see it's a blank variable that somehow helps me to complete the code. Also changing the value of the weights in the init part didnt actually change anything in this code and i am wondering why. Here is the whole code i was given to study. Thanks for helping!

```
import numpy as np

class Perceptron:

    def __init__(self,input_length,weights=None):
        if weights is None:
            self.weights= np.ones(input_length)*0.5
        else:
            self.weights=weights
    @staticmethod
    def unit_step_function(x):
        if x>0.5:
            return 1
        return 0
    def __call__(self,in_data):
            weighted_input=self.weights*in_data
            weighted_sum=weighted_input.sum()
            return Perceptron.unit_step_function(weighted_sum)
p = Perceptron(2,np.array([0.5,0.5]))

for x in [np.array([0,0]),np.array([0,1]),np.array([1,0]),np.array([1,1])]:

    y=p(np.array(x))
    print(x,y)
```

Comment: [The Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/) is extensive and very good. Including its tutorials. Please take some time to go through it.

Answer (score 0):

`__call__` is called when you try to invoke the object as though it were a function. You can see that being done at the bottom. `p` is a Perceptron object, but it's being treated as a function when you write

```
y = p(np.array(x))
```

So where is the data coming from? It's the `np.array(x)` that's being passed in.

You can read more about the "dunder"/"magic" methods [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names).

---

I'd actually argue that this is an abuse of `__call__` though. I wouldn't consider a Perceptron to be inherently function-like. I think using a normal method would be clearer:

```
class Perceptron:
    . . .

    def give_input(self, in_data):  # Instead of __call__
            weighted_input = self.weights*in_data
            weighted_sum = weighted_input.sum()
            return Perceptron.unit_step_function(weighted_sum)

for x in [np.array([0,0]),np.array([0,1]),np.array([1,0]),np.array([1,1])]:
    y = p.give_input(np.array(x))  # Just a typical method call now
```